# Change the allocate size of buffer doesn't change output of the program

Tags: c#, buffer, fixed

```
using System;

namespace Page189
{
    unsafe struct UnsafeUnicodeString
    {
        public short Length;
        public fixed byte Buffer[30]; // Allocate block of 30 bytes, I change the 30 to 1, expected to have some outofboundary exception, but nothing happens

    unsafe class UnsafeClass
    {
        UnsafeUnicodeString uus;

        public UnsafeClass(string s)
        {
            uus.Length = (short) s.Length;
            fixed (byte* p = uus.Buffer)


                for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                {
                    p[i] = (byte) s[i];
                    Console.Write((char)p[i]);//this line is added by myself
                }
            }
        }

        class Test
        {
            static void Main()
            {
                new UnsafeClass("Christian Troy");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am reading book c#6.0 in a NutShell, on page 189, there is an example program of Fixed-Sized buffers. I changed the line

```
public fixed byte Buffer[30]
```

to

```
public fixed byte Buffer[1]
```

and I am expecting to have some out of boundary exceptions but program still running the same with no errors. In the example "Christian Troy" is more than 1 length. Could some one please explain why?

Comment: Because this is unmanaged code, you will not get any exceptions. Instead  you will get unpredictable behaviour. There is no bounds-checking like in managed code

Comment: Hi How I can change to use managed code? thanks!

Comment: By not using `unsafe` related functions. E.g. pointers... (pure managed code does not use `unsafe` variables, classes, structs etc)

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem, however this doesn't answer why the code would still work after you change it to Buffer[1], I'm also interested into its explanation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not crash because you declared `p` as a pointer (`byte* p`). For this reason, `p[i] = (byte) s[i];` is not accessing the buffer through the `Array` class, but is directly manipulating the inner memory.
Your instruction is turned into something similar to (pseudo code)

`memory(addressof(p) + (i * sizeof(byte))) = (byte) s[i];`

The behavior is unpredictable and depends on how the memory is laid out. Particularly, in your case, you are overwriting a portion of memory allocated to your process after your variable storage. As your are dealing with few bytes, your are not getting any exception.

If you write a very long string, let's say 5000 characters, you will try to smash that segment currupting much more, and you'll see the exception.

Try this:

`new UnsafeClass(new string ('a', 5000));`

Comment: Hi Pier, thanks a lot for your kind explanation, that really same as you said. I appreciate your kind help!